# ¿Como asignar checked a input checkbox desde javaScript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, input, switch

Estoy tratando de que con un botón agregue el checked y encienda todos los switch checkbox, con el atributo checked=true, pero aunque le asigno el checked=true, no encienden los switch.

He pensado en que debe haber una forma en la que accecer al input de forma nativa como si lo estuviera creando para poder encerderlo con el checked, pero no he encontrado la forma, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

He intentando esto:

```
$(this)[0].setAttribute("checked", true);
$(this)[0].checked = true;
$(this).get(0).checked = true;
```

pero no funciona
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Hay alguna forma de acceder al DOM para poder encender el switch checkbox desde javaScript?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Asigna .prop('checked', 1). Veo que estás usando JQuery. Consulta [PropertyName](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value). La asignación mediante attr no es el mejor camino porque los atributos se establecen durante la carga del DOM (y algunas veces no se percibe su reasignación) mientras que prop() actua en todo momento, particularmente, en tiempo de ejecución y siempre es perceptible su efecto.

Answer (score 2):

Para activar el checkbox:

```
$("#myCheckbox").prop("checked", true) ;
```

Para comprobar si está marcado:

```
if ($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked"))
```

Comment: Convendría que expliques un poco tu respuesta. ¿Por qué razón debe usar .prop() en lugar de .attr() ? No se trata de simplemente decir haz esto o lo otro ... tratamos de que se pueda aprender de las respuestas